# google maps javascript api v3 - Finding lat/lng for a point on road given nearby lat/lng of a marker and distance from it in miles

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a marker on a road with lat/lng, Now I know there is an Incident on road on X- Miles from that marker point.. Is there any way to track the lat/lng of the new point where incident has happened ?

any help ?

Comment: Do you have a location along the road past the incident?  If you have that, and your "marker on a road", you can get the route between your marker and the point past the incident, then calculate a point along that route where the incident should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that places markers on a route at specific distances along the route (9.5km and 64.8km):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html